# How to make a textview to wrap its content but also alignBottom to another textview?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have this textview, tv1, and it contains 4 lines of words. I have this second textview, tv2, and it will vary from 1 line of text to 6 lines of text. How can I make tv1 always show 4 lines of text, but expand when tv2's text goes to 6 lines of text?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labeltvItem1Pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvMagRes"
    android:layout_below="@+id/labeltvSpeed"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvItem1Pass"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/tvItem1Pass"
    android:text="Passive from first item: "
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvItem1Pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="460dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvMagRes"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Nothing"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Beautiful paint image:

[image]

Feel free to rephrase this question if its confusing

I've tried to change around the code with no success. Any more help?

Comment: Can you post your layout xml? The parent layout might make a difference.

Comment: @myanimal My layout xml is relativelayout if that's what you are asking

Comment: I don't fully understand your layout. Are the TextViews next to each other, like columns? Does tv1 have more than 4 lines of text, but only shows 4 lines? Do you want tv1 to match tv2 in height if tv2 is taller than tv1?

Comment: @myanimal The textviews are next to each other. Their top is at the same level, whereas I want the bottom to vary. tv1's text won't change ever, so I just want to change tv2

Comment: It should be as simple as setting both `TextView`s to  have `layout_height="wrap_content"`. What exactly is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: @myanimal The problem is although the TextView does wrap the content, the height of it is compressed because tv2 is only one line long, and so therefore tv1 is one line long.

Comment: Can you post your full layout xml?

Comment: @Piofmc a picture (with background color on the TextViews with desired behaviour) in each situation would help. I read what you're saying, but I cannot understand what you mean. Then someone may be able to rephrase the question for you too, which will help future visitors with similar issues

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labeltvItem1Pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Passive from first item: "
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItem1Pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Nothing"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

then try this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weight_sum="10"
    android:gravity="bottom"
     >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labeltvItem1Pass"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:text="Passive from first item: "
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvItem1Pass"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:text="Nothing"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This completely messes up the layout, and BTW, just edit your first post and it is weightSum, not weight_sum